# Fedora: 'GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory'

Tags: c++, linux, fedora

I am very new to C when trying to `make` some example code I get the error

```
basic.cc:18:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
```

On further inspection the contents of the Makefile are

```
# This Makefile assumes that you have GLFW libraries and headers installed on,
# which is commonly available through your distro's package manager.
# On Debian and Ubuntu, GLFW can be installed via `apt install libglfw3-dev`.

COMMON=-O2 -I../include -L../lib -std=c++17 -pthread -Wl,-no-as-needed -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'/../lib

all:
    $(CXX) $(COMMON) testxml.cc            -lmujoco          -o ../bin/testxml
    $(CXX) $(COMMON) testspeed.cc          -lmujoco          -o ../bin/testspeed
    $(CXX) $(COMMON) compile.cc            -lmujoco          -o ../bin/compile
    $(CXX) $(COMMON) derivative.cc         -lmujoco -fopenmp -o ../bin/derivative
    $(CXX) $(COMMON) basic.cc              -lmujoco -lglfw   -o ../bin/basic
    $(CXX) $(COMMON) record.cc             -lmujoco -lglfw   -o ../bin/record
```

As I am on fedora I installed `glfw` through dnf

```
sudo dnf install glfw
```

but the its files are now in `/usr/lib64/` where gcc does not see them ([package information](https://fedora.pkgs.org/35/fedora-x86_64/glfw-3.3.4-3.fc35.x86_64.rpm.html)).

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked `glfw` package contains the compiled shared library only, but for development you also need [`glfw-devel`](https://fedora.pkgs.org/35/fedora-x86_64/glfw-devel-3.3.4-3.fc35.x86_64.rpm.html) package which contains the headers.

> but the its files are now in /usr/lib64/ where gcc does not see them

It should see them, but that comes at play later during linking, the `Makefile` correctly adds `-lglfw` so it should work.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand it a bit better now.